# Loading MP3 files at runtime in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load an mp3 file at runtime using the [`WWW`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class that is provided in Unity.

I don't get any errors, but I'm unable to play the music after the song has been processed. I have looked everywhere and cannot find anything to help me.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
public class OpenFile : MonoBehaviour {
    string path;
    string extension;
    public GameObject musicAnalysis;
    string songName;
    float length;
    AudioSource song;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        song =  musicAnalysis.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(song.isPlaying != true){
            song.Play();
        }
    }

    public void FileSelect(){
        //Open windows Exploer 
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Select a Song","","");

        print(path);

        //Take the end of the the path and sasve it to another string
        extension = path.Substring(path.IndexOf('.') + 1);

        print (extension);
        //Check if the user has select the correct file
        if(extension == "mp3" || extension == "wav" || extension == "ogg"){
            //if correct file process file
            print ("You have selected the correct file type congrats");

            LoadSong();
            print ("Song Name: " + songName);
            print ("Song Length: " + length);
        }
        //if the user selects the wrong file type
        else{
            //pop up box that tells the user that they have selected the wrong file
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error","Incorrect File Type Please select another","Ok");
            ////Open windows Exploer 
            path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Select a Song","","");
        }
    }

    void LoadSong(){
        WWW www = new WWW("file://" + path);
        song.clip = www.audioClip;
        songName =  www.audioClip.name;
        length = www.audioClip.length;

        while(!www.isDone){
            print ("Processing File" + path);
        }

        if(www.isDone == true){
            print ("Song has been processed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you on? MP3 is not supported on Windows.

Comment: I'm using Windows. Do you know of any alternatives I have also tried ogg and wav @peterept

Comment: You can definately use ogg or wav (make sure the files have the correct extension). The reason your code doesn't work above for those is because you aren't waiting for the www to complete. I'll give you the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted above, windows doesn't support MP3, so use OGG or WAV.
Edit: This method do in fact work with mp3, I tested it with multiple files on Unity 2019.3.6f

You must wait for WWW to complete before accessing the clip. And WWW must be loaded in an asynchronouse Coroutine.

```
public void LoadSong()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadSongCoroutine());    
}

IEnumerator LoadSongCoroutine()
{
    string url = string.Format("file://{0}", path); 
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    song.clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, false);
    songName =  song.clip.name;
    length = song.clip.length;
}
```

Comment: It worked perfect thanks a lot for your help.Ii can mange with wav files for now. I have one more questions maybe you can help me out. the lines
    songName =  song.clip.name;
    length = song.clip.length;
 when I print them to the console, nothing appears.@peterept

Comment: The length is supposed to be seconds, but it will some times return null depending on the encoding of the encoding of the audio.

Comment: does not work in Unity 2019, says "Streaming of 'mpeg' on this platform is not supported"

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK loading mp3s in Windows in Unity is not directly supported (2019.4.1)

Using the [NLayer](https://github.com/naudio/NLayer) library this worked for me

```
IEnumerator LoadHelper(string uri)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
      // Or retrieve results as binary data
      byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
      var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(results);
      var mpgFile = new NLayer.MpegFile(memStream);
      var samples = new float[mpgFile.Length];
      mpgFile.ReadSamples(samples, 0, (int)mpgFile.Length);

      var clip = AudioClip.Create("foo", samples.Length, mpgFile.Channels, mpgFile.SampleRate, false);
      clip.SetData(samples, 0);
      source.clip = clip;
    }
}
```

`source` as an `AudioSource`.

Example project [here](https://github.com/greggman/unity-load-mp3-at-runtime) and HTML build [here](https://greggman.github.io/unity-load-mp3-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioImporter (https://github.com/Hello-Meow/AudioImporter), and will support mp3 in conjunction with the commercial BASS library (see the readme).

It says you can begin playback of the resultant audioClip as soon as the first buffer is returned - I'm just testing that myself now.