# Playing AudioClip fetched from Resources folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to fetch the audioClip in the resources folder so as I understand I need to use `Resources.Load<AudioClip>(path)` or `Resources.Load(path) as AudioClip` but this just doesn't work, it doesn't even return a null it just stops the code

my code sample:

```
private void FetchAudioClipAndStartPlay(int userPos, int index)
{


    AudioClip clip = Resources.Load($"Audio/Demo_ENG/D{userPos}a") as AudioClip;
    Debug.Log("Starting Coroutine " + index);
    StartCoroutine(PlayAudioClipAndStartRetrievingFromDatabase(index, clip));
}

IEnumerator PlayAudioClipAndStartRetrievingFromDatabase(int index, AudioClip clip)
{
    Debug.Log("Starting to play " + index);
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip, 1f);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clip.length);

    if (index < numberOfPlayers)
    {
        RetrieveFromDatabase(index++);
    }
}
```

(it doesn't enter the coroutine)

[image]

[image]

All the audio files are .mp3

Any guidance and tips are very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unity does not support loading mp3 at runtime.
2. Unity [does not recommend using the `Resources` folder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7):

> **Don't use it.**
>   This strong recommendation is made for several reasons:
>
> - Use of the Resources folder makes fine-grained memory management more
>     difficult Improper use of Resources folders will increase application
>     startup time and the length of builds
> - As the number of Resources
>     folders increases, management of the Assets within those folders
>     becomes very difficult
> - The Resources system degrades a project's
>     ability to deliver custom content to specific platforms and
>     eliminates the possibility of incremental content upgrades
>     AssetBundle Variants are Unity's primary tool for adjusting content
>     on a per-device basis

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30857437/11835930) for a solution how to load audio files:

```
public void LoadSong()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadSongCoroutine());    
}

IEnumerator LoadSongCoroutine()
{
    string url = string.Format("file://{0}", path); 
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    song.clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, false);
    songName =  song.clip.name;
    length = song.clip.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working quite well, but what if I need it to work on a phone? wouldn't the path be different?

Comment: Yes, both Android and iOS have their own folder structure. You can look into [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). There are some more special paths in that class that will help you to remain platform-independent.